# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality of the carré du champ operator

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, functional-analysis, functions

I want to prove the inequality $$\Gamma(f,g)^2 \leq \Gamma(f,f) \Gamma(g,g) \ \mu \text {-almost everywhere}$$ for $f, g \in \mathcal{A}$ where $\Gamma$ denotes the carré du champ operator. More precisely:
Let $(E, \mathcal{E})$ be a Polish space with $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$. The function $\Gamma: \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ is symmetric, bilinear and satisfies $\Gamma(f,f) \geq 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere for all $f \in \mathcal{A}$. $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $L^\infty(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ which is dense in $L^p(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$.

My idea was to copy the proof of Cauchy Schwarz's inequality. We obtain
$$
0 \leq \Gamma(f - \lambda g, f - \lambda g) = \Gamma(f,f) - 2\lambda\Gamma(f,g) + \lambda^2 \Gamma(g,g)
$$
$\mu$-almost everywhere for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. But i cannot justify the argument defining $\lambda := \frac{\Gamma(f,g)}{\Gamma(g,g)}$ since the non-negativity of $\Gamma(f - \lambda g, f - \lambda g)$ is just $\mu$ almost everywhere where the sets of measure zero might depend on $\lambda$.

Annother idea is to use Cauchy Schwarz's inequality for the bilinear form $(f,g) \mapsto \int \Gamma(f,g) \varphi d \mu$ for fixed $\varphi \in L^1(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$, $\varphi \geq 0$. We obtain
$$
\left ( \int \Gamma(f,g) \varphi d \mu \right )^2 \leq  \int \Gamma(f,f) \varphi d \mu \int \Gamma(g,g) \varphi d \mu 
$$ but I don't know how to get a pointwise estimate from that. Tto the best of my knowledge, Lebesgue differentiation theorem fail in general Polish spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument shows that for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a set $A_\lambda$ of full measure such that we have 
$$0 \leq  \Gamma(f,f)(x) - 2\lambda\Gamma(f,g)(x) + \lambda^2 \Gamma(g,g)(x) \tag{*}$$
for all $x \in A_{\lambda}$.  Let $A = \bigcap_{\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}} A_{\lambda}$ which again has full measure.  Now fix $x \in A$.  We have that (*) holds for every rational $\lambda$, and since the right side is continuous in $\lambda$, it holds for all real $\lambda$.  Now we proceed as usual, taking $\lambda = \Gamma(f,g)(x) / \Gamma(g,g)(x)$ and rearrange to show $$\Gamma(f,g)(x)^2 \le \Gamma(f,f)(x) \Gamma(g,g)(x) \tag{**}$$
As usual, if $\Gamma(g,g)(x)=0$ then you just send $\lambda \to \pm\infty$ in (*) to see that $\Gamma(f,g)(x)=0$ in this case.  So (**) holds for every $x$ in $A$, and $A$ had full measure.